# How to deploy phonegap app to ipad/iphone

Tags: ios, ipad

I am totally new to making ipad/iphone application.  I am totally new to using phonegap.   I downloaded a HelloWorld application and opened it up with xcode.  it works fine in simulator.  So i tried to deploy it to my iPad.  When I hit Build and Run in xcode, i get this error:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain.
```

I have no idea what this means.  I applied for the Apple Developer program a few months ago.  I got back an email saying I successfully enrolled.  Do I need to copy some kind of certificate from my Apple Account on the website to my ipad to enable xcode to deploy my helloworld program to the ipad?

I am totally confused on how to test the HelloWorld application on my iPad....

**Additional Notes**

OK, i followed some steps on how to sign a certificate and install it in xcode.  Now when I try to Build and Run to a device, I get this error:

`Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'forgelink' specifies the Application Identifier 'forgelink' which doesn't match the current setting 'R8T3VN6VR7.forgelink.forgelink'`

Did I type something wrong when creating my certificates, bundle identifiers, app ids etc...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to get developer certificates (code signing certificates) from your apple developer site.
log into developer.apple.com and follow the steps

Edit:

Here's the link to iOS Provisioning portal
http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Comment: I'm on the 99$/year plan.  I do not have privileges to go to http://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action to obtain signing certificates.  Do i need to buy a different plan from apple to buy certificates?  Apple support has not yet responded to my questions.

Comment: Added a link to provisional portal

Comment: ok, now i get the error `Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'forgelink' specifies the Application Identifier 'forgelink' which doesn't match the current setting 'R8T3VN6VR7.forgelink.forgelink'`

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was using a Hackintosh instead of a legitimate version of OSX.  Hackintosh doesn't play nice with code signing certificates

Comment: Oh man. I hope I don't run into such an annoying problem with my Hackintosh too. :\

Answer (score 9):

To summarize, as I've just spent a whole day trying to deploy to iOS devices through xcode:

1. You must pay the $99 + $7 in tax, to join the Apple Developer Network and deploy to actual devices
2. You setup this association in XCode by signing in using you AppleID.
3. You must give the unique device ID to Apple, along with signing a request and downloading a cert in order to use any real devices.  Just follow their tutorial exactly, especially the copying of the .mobileprovisioning file: [Apple's Provisioning Tool (sigin with your apple ID if it doesn't work)](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

   I created a provisioning profile for every apple device I hooked up to my computer, but maybe you can do it with one...
4. Your device will now show up in the dropdown menu next to the play button in XCode.  If not, the provisioning didn't complete successfully, and you need to go back and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a developer certificate and create a provisioning profile. The [Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) has detailed instructions and links, and a nice portal for creating and downloading the profiles.